# How to import library "Application", because package Application not found to import

Tags: android

```
public class Home extends Application{
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


  }
}
```

**Application** not found, can you help me please ?

Comment: On the top left corner of Android Studio,hit `file` then `Invalidate Cashes/Restart`

Comment: not work brow...

Answer (score 0):

In you module `build.gradle` file, add below line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

and **sync project with gradle files** again.

**Edit**:
Really strange! may be you could **reinstall** android studio and create an **android** project from wizard.